# Trouble with the derivative of the delta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

I am trying to evaluate the following integral with Mathematica:

\begin{align}
I = \int_{0}^{\infty}  da  \,    \frac{e^{-\frac{a ^2}{4s^2}} }{a^2} \mbox{sinc}\left(\tfrac{w}{2} a \right)   \delta' \left(  \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right),
\end{align}
where the prime on the delta function denotes differentiation with respect to the argument of the Delta function. When I evaluate this integral with Mathematica as:

```
Integrate[Exp[-a^2/(4 s^2)]/a^2 Sinc[w a / 2] Derivative[1][DiracDelta][D^2/a - a],{a,0,Infinity}, Assumptions -> s > 0 && w > 0 && D > 0]
```

I get the result:
\begin{align}
I_{Mathematica} = \frac{e^{-\frac{D^2}{4 s ^2}} }{4 D^4 s ^2 w } \left[\left(D^2+6 s ^2\right) \sin \left(\frac{D w }{2}\right)-D s ^2 w  \cos \left(\frac{D w }{2}\right)\right].
\end{align}

However, if I evaluate this integral analytically, using the fact that
\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{da} \delta\left( \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right) = - \delta' \left( \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right)  \left(\frac{D^2}{a^2}+1\right) \implies \delta' \left( \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right)  = - \left[\frac{d}{da} \delta\left( \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right) \right] \left(\frac{D^2}{a^2}+1\right)^{-1},
\end{align}
I get the following result:
\begin{align}
 I_{analytic} &=   \int_{0}^{\infty}  da  \,    \frac{e^{-\frac{a ^2}{4s^2}} }{a^2} \frac{\sin \left(\tfrac{w}{2} a \right) }{\tfrac{w}{2} a}  \delta' \left(  \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right)  \\
 &=-  \int_{0}^{\infty}  da  \,   \left[\frac{d}{da} \delta\left( \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right) \right] \left(\frac{D^2}{a^2}+1\right)^{-1}  \frac{e^{-\frac{a ^2}{4s^2}} }{a^2} \frac{\sin \left(\tfrac{w}{2} a \right) }{\tfrac{w}{2} a}    \\
  &=   \int_{0}^{\infty}  da  \,   \delta\left( \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right) \left[\frac{d}{da}   \left(\frac{D^2}{a^2}+1\right)^{-1}  \frac{e^{-\frac{a ^2}{4s^2}} }{a^2} \frac{\sin \left(\tfrac{w}{2} a \right) }{\tfrac{w}{2} a} \right]  \\
   &=   \int_{0}^{\infty}  da  \,   \frac{\delta\left( D - a \right)}{2} \left[\frac{d}{da}   \left(\frac{D^2}{a^2}+1\right)^{-1}  \frac{e^{-\frac{a ^2}{4s^2}} }{a^2} \frac{\sin \left(\tfrac{w}{2} a \right) }{\tfrac{w}{2} a} \right]  \\
   &= - \frac{e^{-\frac{ D^2 }{ 4s^{2}}}}{4 D^{4} s^{2} w} \left[ \left(D^{2}+4 s^{2}\right)\sin\left( \frac{ Dw}{2} \right) - D s^{2} w \cos \left( \frac{ Dw}{2} \right)  \right],
\end{align}
which differs from $I_{Mathematica}$ by an overall negative sign and the prefactor in front of $s^2$ in the first term.

I'm not sure if the issue is with the way Mathematica handles the derivative of the delta function or if I've made a mistake in my analytic calculation. Any help would be much appreciated, I've been staring at this for days!

Comment: Perhaps your analytical formula is wrong? As far as I know  `DiracDelta'[x]==-DiracDelta[x]/x` , which is different from your "fact".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! There could be a mistake in the analytic formula, but I have gone through it now several times as have others. Also, I'm not sure about the identity you quote involving the derivative of the delta function. I believe $\delta'(x) = - \delta(x) \frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: You might check the formula with Mathematica: `Integrate[ x Derivative[1][DiracDelta][x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]==-1`

Comment: I agree with the expression you write because the integral is over x, which is also the argument of the delta function. However, in the case above, the argument of the delta function is a function of the integration variable $a$. Does this not change things? That is the point of the "fact", although perhaps I'm mistaken there.

Comment: The formula holds for arbitrary argument!

Comment: Thanks for the discussion! Note that the bounds are differnt so that ```Integrate[ x Derivative[1][DiracDelta][x], {x, 0, Infinity}] == - 1 + HeavisideTheta[0]```.

Comment: Also, ``Integrate[ x Derivative[1][DiracDelta][x], {x, 0, Infinity}]'' is not equal to ```Integrate[ 
 x^2  Derivative[1][DiracDelta][(x - 1)^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]```. However, presumably when you say `The formula holds for any argument', then also the integration measure would change. I believe this is equivalent to the "fact" I stated above. Note I use quotations around "fact" to leave open the possibility that there may be a mistake there, but I do not see one.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215063/how-to-find-the-variational-result-of-this-functional-according-to-the-definitio) will help you.

Comment: The integral under consideration makes no sense in the distribution theory (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_function ). Such primitive approach leads to wrong results in many cases and this is a reason  why the distribution theory was developed

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand why you say that the integral under consideration makes no sense. $e^{-a^2/(4 s^2)} \mbox{Sinc}[w a / 2]$ appears to me to be a valid test function on which the derivative of the delta function can act, the derivative of the delta function is a well-defined distribution. What is primitive about the approach?

Comment: @e4alex s/he says that every time the Dirac delta-function is mentioned, don't worry.

Comment: @user64494 You are right at stating that the integral posted by the original OP is not well defined. Yet, do you realize that the reason it is wrong is the same reason [your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/218510/70331) is wrong. *You cannot change the limits of integration at will*.

Comment: @SolutionExists: I'm not sure why you say the integral is well defined. If it is because of the limits of integration, one could also multiply the test function by a Heaviside function $\theta(a)$.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Did you intend that derivative to be -Delta[x]*x ? As for the finite bound of integration, it just has to not have a singularity at that finite endpoint. So it is fine provided `D!=0`.

Comment: ...and now I see @AestheticAnalyst gave a nice exposition of my second statement.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau This was my basic idea, learned some time ago: `Derivative[1][DiracDelta][x]==-DiracDelta[x]/x` . I'll try to apply to the general problem...

Comment: `Integrate[DiracDelta'[x] f[x], {x, -1, 1}]` gives `-f'[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's talk about the Dirac $\delta$-"function". Strictly speaking, it's a linear functional
$$\delta:C^\infty(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R\qquad\qquad\delta(f)=f(0).$$
However, we usually use the notation
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)f(x)dx$$
to denote the evaluation $\delta(f)$. The derivative of the $\delta$-"function" is computed via formal integration by parts:
$$\delta'(f)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta'(x)f(x)dx=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)f'(x)dx=-f'(0).$$
Your integral has the additional complications that there is a function inside the argument of $\delta'(x)$, and that the integral is not taken over all of $\mathbb R$. Composing distributions with functions is, in general, not possible, but in this case we can appeal to a theorem of Hormander:

**Theorem:** *Suppose $f:M\to N$ is a smooth function whose differential is everywhere surjective. Then there is a linear map $f^*:\mathscr D(N)\to\mathscr D(M)$ such that $f^*u=u\circ f$ for all $u\in C(N)$.*

For our purposes, this means $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta'(f(x))g(x)dx$ makes sense provided $f(x)$ is smooth and $f'(x)$ never vanishes. Similarly, reducing the domain of integration is, in general, not possible, but we have:

**Theorem** *Suppose $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint closed sets, and let $\mathscr D_{E_i}$ denote the set of distributions which coincide with a smooth function on $E_i^c$ for $i=1,2$. Then there is a bilinear map 
$$m:\mathscr D_{E_1}\times\mathscr D_{E_2}\to\mathscr D(\mathbb R^n)$$ 
such that $m(u,v)=uv$ when $u$ and $v$ are continuous.*

In our case, we would like to compute the integral
$$\int_0^\infty\delta'\left(\frac{D^2}{x}-x\right)g(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)\delta'\left(\frac{D^2}{a}-a\right)g(x)dx,$$
where $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$ is the characteristic function of the half-line $(0,\infty)$. The theorem says that the product
$$\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)\delta'\left(\frac{D^2}{x}-x\right)$$
makes sense whenever the singular support of $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$, namely $\{0\}$, does not intersect the singular support of $\delta'\left(\frac{D^2}{x}-x\right)$, namely $\{D,-D\}$. Thus when $D\neq 0$, our integral makes sense and
$$\int_0^\infty\delta'\left(\frac{D^2}{x}-x\right)g(x)dx=\begin{cases}g'(D),&D>0\\g(-D),&D<0\end{cases}.$$
To compute your integral, just plug in your particular function $g(x)$. When you're working with distributions (like $\delta$) you need to be very careful about what you do with them. I don't know how Mathematica conceptualizes the $\delta$-distribution, but I wouldn't be inclined trust that it would go through the necessary analytical reasoning and get the right answer.

TL;DR: Do your distributional calculus by hand.

Comment: Thank you so much for those theorems that rigorously justify the composition and multiplication of distribution, placing the integral we seek to evaluate on solid ground! The detailed reply is much appreciated.

Comment: @ AestheticAnalyst  However, I'm not sure I agree with the evaluation of the integral in your last equation, or perhaps it was misunderstood what was meant by $\delta'(f(x))$.  Consider $\frac{d}{dx} ( \frac{D^2}{x} - x )= - \delta'( \frac{D^2}{x} - x ) \left(\frac{D^2}{x^2}+1 \right)$.

Comment: @ AnethesticAnalyst It follows that: 
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \delta'\left( \frac{D^2}{x} - x \right) g(x) \, dx &= -  \int_0^\infty  \left(\frac{D^2}{x^2}+1 \right)^{-1}  g(x) \frac{d}{dx} \delta \left( \frac{D^2}{x} - x \right) \, dx \\
&=  \int_0^\infty  \frac{d}{dx}  \left[ \left(\frac{D^2}{x^2}+1 \right)^{-1}  g(x) \right]  \delta\left( \frac{D^2}{x} - x \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \left(\frac{D^2}{x^2}+1 \right)^{-1}  g(x) \right]_{x = D}
\end{align}
Would you agree?

Comment: @AestheticAnalyst Thank you for this interesting contribution. One remark: Assuming ( [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) ) `Derivative[1][DiracDelta][x]==-DiracDelta[x]/x` I would get something like `Integrate[g[x],x] Derivative[1][DiracDelta][x],{x,0,Infinity}]=-g[a]/(d^2 -a) /.a->d` without distinguishing cases of d!

Comment: @e4alex As an exercise, integrate by parts $\int f(x) g'(|x|) dx$. The absolute value there forces you to think of $g$ as an even function. Dirac's delta is an even distribution. That will correct your extra minus sign.

Comment: Hi, there is this still [unanswered post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208095/problem-with-antiderivative-which-involves-diracdelta). Would be nice if you can provide some mathematical insight.

Comment: The function $ \chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ is not smooth on $(-\infty,\infty)$. Can you elaborate how the theorem which requires smoothness is applied? TIA.

Comment: @yarchik Regarding that prior post, feel free to take my comments as: "The math does not support the given result. Unevaluated would be better. A message that the singular integral is undefined would also be nice."

Comment: @SolutionExists I agree that the Dirac delta function is even, $\delta(-x) = \delta(x)$. Also, note that $\frac{d}{dx} \delta(-x) = \frac{d}{dx} \delta(x)$. However, $\delta'(-x) = - \delta'(x)$, where the prime denotes differntiation with respect to the argument of the delta function. This latter property illustrates that $\delta'(x)$ is odd in $x$. These propoerties are summarized here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Distributional_derivatives Do you agree?

Comment: @SolutionExists To evaluate the integral you suggest, I will interpret the prime as differentiation with respect to $|x|$. Then observe $\frac{dg(|x|)}{dx} = g'(|x|) \frac{d |x|}{dx} = g'(|x|) \frac{x}{|x|}$. Then the integral in question becoems 
\begin{align}
\int dx\, f(x) g'(|x|) = \int dx\, f(x)  \frac{|x|}{x} \frac{dg(|x|)}{dx} = - \int dx \, \frac{d}{dx} \left(f(x)  \frac{|x|}{x} \right) g(|x|)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Here my attempt to solve the integral `Integrate[f[a] Derivative[1][DiracDelta][d^2/a - a],{a,0,Infinity}]`:

```
f[a_] := Exp[-a^2/(4 s^2)]/a^2 Sinc[w a/2]
```

Substitution `u[a]=d^2/a-a` (integrationlimits change to u[0]=Infinity],u[Infinity]=-Infinity)

```
u[a_] := d^2/a - a

sola = Solve[u == d^2/a - a, a][[2]] (*solution a>0*)
```

Now Mathematica is able to solve the integral

```
int=Integrate[f[a/.sola] Derivative[1][DiracDelta][u]/u'[a]/.sola ,{u, Infinity,-Infinity}]

(*(E^(-(d^2/(4 s^2))) (d s^2 w Cos[(d w)/2] - (d^2 + 4 s^2) Sin[(d w)/2]))/(4 d^3 Sqrt[d^2] s^2 w)*)
```

Hope it helps solving your problem!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I agree with your approach and it agrees with the result I get from $I_{analytic}$. This is the result I trust, however, when I evaluate 

```Integrate[Exp[-a^2/(4 s^2)] Sinc[w a / 2] Derivative[1][DiracDelta][D^2/a - a],{a,0,Infinity}, Assumptions -> s > 0 && w > 0 && D > 0]```, which appears to be the same integral, I get $I_{Mathematica} \neq I_{analytic}$. This is the source of my confusion. Do you see why these two integrals give differnt results? Is it something wrong with how code $I_{Mathematica}$?

Comment: @e4alex I agree and think that Mathematica result, which only differs in sign, is wrong. You get the  Mathematica result if you take the first branch of `sola[…][[1]]`! One additional remark: Substitution `d^2->d2` helps mathematica a lot...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I do not think MMA result is wrong. The fact that Dirac's delta only has meaning within an integral does not mean that you can change the limits of integration at will. The limits of integration are an integral part  of the definition.

Comment: @SolutionExists Thanks for your comment, I didn't change the integration limits at will. My point is the transformation `a->u` , which must cover the integration range `0<a<Infinity` . That's why I think `sola[[2]]` is the right branch (and Mathematica perhaps took the wrong)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I didn't mean you personally, I meant in general. The integral in the OP goes from zero to ∞, but the definition of Dirac's delta *must* use an integral from -∞ to ∞. Changing the limits of the integral to [0,∞) is equivalent to multiply to test function by a Heaviside theta, so the OP integral is the integral of a distribution times a distribution. That is doable but not trivial.

Comment: @SolutionExists The integral isn't meaningsless, your argumentation is only ok if the argument of the DeltaDistribution is the same as the variable of integration. As you you can see in my answer after transforming `a->u` the integration variable , the limits become `{u,-Infinity,Infinity} ` as you correctly require for the definition of dirac!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  The delta function is an even distribution. If you extend the subintegral with $f(-x)=-f(x)$, you get a different answer than if you extend the subintegral with $f(-x)=f(x)$. The correct way to deal with the OP integral is to do it the Physics way: find the zeros of the δ, evaluate around those points; if there are derivatives of the δ, use integration by parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106235/discussion-between-solutionexists-and-ulrich-neumann).

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Mathematica produces the same result if one extends the integration bounds to -Infinity to Infinity and includes a Heaviside functions in the integrand. That is $I_{Mathematica}$ is the same as quoted in the original post.

Comment: @SolutionExists: When you suggest "doing it the physics way" I believe this is what is done in the analytic approach leading to $I_{analytic}$.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I understand my error now, your approach is correct.

Comment: Just a small question, is your $d$ (or $D$ in OP, @e4alex) positive or negative. This needs to be specified.

Comment: @SolutionExists  Thanks, for our interesting discussion!

Comment: @yarchik Maybe it's positive. Shouldn't be important because only `d^2, D^2` is considered.

Comment: @yarchik Ultimately, I would like to know the answer for either D>0 or D<0. However, in the original post, I set D>0 to be specific. Note that if one instead assumes D<0 then Mathematica returns the negative of $I_{Mathematica}$.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer and comments were wrong. I didn't notice the argument of the δ function was not linear in the integration variable (and I wasn't even drunk).

In the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), there is this paragraph

> In the integral form the generalized scaling property may be written as
>        $∫_{-∞}^∞ f ( x ) δ ( g ( x ) ) d x = ∑_i f ( x_i ) / | g ′ ( x_i ) | $.

The Jacobian of the transformation is 1/g'(x). Please note the absolute value in the denominator.

Basically, find the zeroes of the argument of the δ, and integrate around them (by parts if necessary). Also,

> The distributional derivative of the Dirac delta distribution is the distribution δ′ defined on compactly supported smooth test functions φ by
>   $δ ′ [ φ ] = − δ [ φ ′ ] = − φ ′ ( 0 )$ .

(1) Finding the zeroes:

```
Solve[-a + Δ^2/a == 0, a]
```

(2) Finding the Jacobian:

```
jac = Solve[Dt[-a + Δ^2/a == u[a]], u'[a]] 
  /. Dt[Δ] → 0 /. a → Δ // FullSimplify
```

(3) Evaluating the integral by parts (don't forget the minus sign in front):

```
v1 = -D[(E^(-(a^2/(4 s^2))) Sinc[(a w)/2])/a^2, a] / Abs[jac]
  /. a → Δ // FullSimplify
```

(4) Divide the integral by the Jacobian (the previous division was because of the integration by parts, this one because of the scaling):

```
v1 / Abs[ jac ]
```

The answer is the same as $I_{MMA}$. By the way, MMA is simply using

```
Integrate[ f[a] DiracDelta'[2 a], {a, -∞, ∞}]
(*-(1/4) f'[0]*)
```

Prove that analytically and you will find the error in your analytic calculation.

Comment: Many thanks for replies in answering this question. I am able to prove the last expression you suggest by the methods I use above, so I still don't see the error in my analytic calculation. Observe $\frac{d}{da} \delta(2 a) = 2 \delta'(2a)$. It then follows that:
\begin{align}
\int da \, f(a) \delta'(2a) &= \int da \, f(a) \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{da} \delta(2 a)  \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int da \, \left( \frac{d}{da} f(a) \right)  \delta(2 a)  \\
&= -\frac{1}{4} \int da \, \left( \frac{d}{da} f(a) \right)  \delta(a)  \\
&= -\frac{1}{4} f'(0)
\end{align}

Comment: @e4alex ok, now we agree that the Jacobian is in the denominator twice. So, the only discrepancy should be the sign. Remember that Dirac's delta is an even function, so only the minus sign from integration by parts is necessary.

Comment: For example, the following minus sign in your post should not be there \begin{align}
 I_{analytic} &=   \int_{0}^{\infty}  da  \,    \frac{e^{-\frac{a ^2}{4s^2}} }{a^2} \frac{\sin \left(\tfrac{w}{2} a \right) }{\tfrac{w}{2} a}  \delta' \left(  \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right)  \\
 &=-  \int_{0}^{\infty}  da  \,   \left[\frac{d}{da} \delta\left( \frac{D^2}{a}- a \right) \right] \left(\frac{D^2}{a^2}+1\right)^{-1}  \frac{e^{-\frac{a ^2}{4s^2}} }{a^2} \frac{\sin \left(\tfrac{w}{2} a \right) }{\tfrac{w}{2} a} 
\end{align}  Also, it seems that there are algebraic errors (you have a 4 where I got a 6).

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the Jacobian appears twice. The first factor of two comes from the chain rule, while the second comes from the scaling property of the delta function. So the negative sign you believe should not be there follows from the chain rule which I state in the original post. Is it that you do not agree with the way I apply the chain rule?

Comment: It appears you get the answer that agrees with Mathematica. Note that I believe $I_{Mathematica}$, as stated in the original post, agrees with your results (note the appearance of a 6 instead of a 4).

Comment: However, the last equality in $I_{analytic}$ is obtained from evaluating 
```D[(D^2/a^2 + 1)^-1 Exp[-(a^2/(4 s^2))]/a^2 Sinc[w/2 a], a] / 2 /. a -> D```, so I don't believe there is an algebraic mistake.

Comment: Consider
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \delta \left( | -3x | \right) = \delta' \left( | -3x | \right) \frac{-3x}{|-3x|} (-3),
\end{align}
which implies that 
\begin{align}
\delta' \left( | -3x | \right)  =  \frac{9x}{|-3x|}  \frac{d}{dx} \delta \left( | -3x | \right) = \frac{3x}{|x|}  \frac{d}{dx} \delta \left( | 3x | \right).
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, apply the chain rule to $\int f(x) δ′(|−3x|) dx$. My bad, I meant integration by parts (the integral equivalent of the chain rule) ... man it's only 10 am here  and I'm already making these mistakes.

Comment: Grrr ... on top of that, my example is, strictly speaking, bad ... the point I am trying to make is: you need the absolute value of the Jacobian. I added some sentence in bold in the main text to stress where it comes from.

Comment: haha no worries, I'm on my second cup of coffee. Applying the above result and integrating by parts yields
\begin{align}
\int dx \, f(x)  \delta' \left( | -3x | \right) &=  \int dx \, f(x)  \frac{3x}{|x|}  \frac{d}{dx} \delta \left( | 3x | \right) \\
&=  \int dx \, \left[ \frac{d}{dx} \left( f(x)  \frac{3x}{|x|} \right) \right]   \delta \left( | 3x | \right) \\
&=  \int dx \, \left[ \frac{d}{dx} \left( f(x)  \frac{3x}{|x|} \right) \right]  \frac{1}{3} \delta \left( | x | \right) \\
&=\left[ \frac{d}{dx} \left( f(x)  \frac{x}{|x|} \right) \right]_{x=0}   
\end{align}

Comment: @SolutionsExist: I agree with the formula you quote $\delta(g(x)) = \sum_i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|}$, where $g(x_i)=0$. In fact, this is used in moving from the third to fourth equality in the derivation of $I_{analytic}$.

Comment: Why do you have 3 in the numerator in the first line of $\int f(x)δ′(|−3x|)dx$ but you have 2 in the denominator of the first line of $\int f(a)δ′(2a)da$?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, the evaluation of $\int da\,  f(a) \delta'(2a)$ is correct. From the chain rule, 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \delta \left( |-3x| \right) = \delta'(|-3x|) \frac{-3x}{|-3x|}( -3) \implies \delta'(|-3x|) =   \frac{|x|}{3}\frac{d}{dx} \delta \left( 3|x| \right).
\end{align}

Comment: Then
\begin{align}
\int dx \,  f(x) \delta'(|-3x|) &= \int dx \,  f(x) \frac{|x|}{3}\frac{d}{dx} \delta \left( 3|x| \right) \\
&=- \frac{1}{3}\int dx \,  \left[\frac{d}{dx} \left( f(x) |x| \right) \right] \delta \left( 3|x| \right) \\
&=- \frac{1}{3}\int dx \,  \left[\frac{d}{dx} \left( f(x) |x| \right) \right] \frac{1}{3}\delta \left( x \right) \\
&=- \frac{1}{9} \left[\frac{d}{dx} \left( f(x) |x| \right) \right]_{x=0}  \\
&=- \frac{1}{9} f(0) 
\end{align}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106296/discussion-between-solutionexists-and-e4alex).

Answer (score 0):

**speculation: 
Mathematica cannot handle `Derivative[1][DiracDelta][1/x-x]`in a right way?**

Here I'll give a simplified example which perhaps shows that Mathematica gives a wrong result, when applied to `Derivative[1][DiracDelta][1/x-x]`!

Let's consider the integral

```
Integrate[Derivative[1][DiracDelta][1/x - x], {x, 0, Infinity} ]
(*0*)
```

which MMA (v12)  evaluates to zero!

Alternatively integration with substitution `u=1/x-x, x=-u/2+Sqrt[1+(u/2)^2]`
(see my first answer)

```
us=D[1/x-x,x]/. x->-u/2+Sqrt[1+(u/2)^2];
Integrate[ Derivative[1][DiracDelta][u]/us, {u, Infinity,-Infinity} ]
(*1/4*)
```

To "proof" the last result I'll consider the deltadistribution as a well known limit

```
dirac = Function[x, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 Pi eps]] (* eps->0 *)

int=Integrate[dirac'[1/x - x], {x, 0, Infinity} ]

(*(E^(1/eps) (-BesselK[0, 1/eps] + BesselK[1, 1/eps]))/(eps^(3/2) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])*)
```

eps->0

```
Simplify[ Normal[Series[int, {eps, 0, 0}]], eps > 0]

(*1/4*)
```

Why can't Mathematica find this result? What's wrong here?