# How to understand that integrals with DiracDelta?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica up to version 12.1 performs

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x]*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
(*1 - HeavisideTheta[0]*)
Integrate[DiracDelta'[x]*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
 (*1 - HeavisideTheta[0]*)
```

However, the obtained results are indeterminate and are not  real numbers. How to understand it? Both [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_function) and [W.Rudin. Functional analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070542368) say nothing about such "integrals".

PS. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218479/trouble-with-the-derivative-of-the-delta-function) is a related question in this forum.

Comment: @Nasser: Sorry, I don't understand your remark at all. Your advice " So if one were to just "ignore" the HeavisideTheta[0] term as undefined, then results is correct" is not serious. I stress again that solid references in my question say nothing about such "integrals". Can you kindly give a reference to it? TIA.

Comment: @Nasser: I will be waiting for a serious answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Nasser: Can you kindly give a reference to such "integrals"? TIA.

Comment: I think the logic of your question is deeply flawed: from the fact that 2 books say nothing about a certain thing you derive that thing is not real or indeterminate. It is like "I do not see viruses, therefore they do not exist". I propose the following resolution. Consider that `Integrate` is a functional that provides you some useful results for a certain class of "arguments". For a broader class of arguments, it still provides some useful results, maybe not for you, but for other people. This is already awesome, despite the fact that the `Integrate` has lost its absolute "eternal" meaning.

Comment: Somebody votes to close my question as "Needs details or clarify". Can that person  explains what  clarification is in need? TIA. I hope in Mathematica MAX  such "integrals" would be better executed.

Comment: @yarchik: Do you think the integrals from the question are OK? Your arguments recall me https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208095/problem-with-antiderivative-which-involves-diracdelta

Comment: Yes, and I would like to explain why. The `Integrate` command of MA comprises several mathematical concepts: the antiderivative, definite integral, etc. But it is not even said which definite integral: the Riemann or the Lebesgue integral, or maybe the Darboux integral, or the Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral, or the Haar integral,or the Itô integral? The point is that `Integrate` relates to them all for certain classes of functions, but it is not a mathematical concept on its own.

Comment: @yarchik: What is "etc."? What is realized by Integrate in the command Integrate[DiracDelta[x]*Exp[-s * x], {x, 0, Infinity}] which performs 1 - HeavisideTheta[0] ? BTW, LaplaceTransfrom[DiracDelta[x], x, s] performs 1 and that is not in accordance with the result of Integrate[DiracDelta[x]*Exp[-s * x], {x, 0, Infinity}] .

Comment: The report   [CASE:4520178] was submitted by me. The obtained response  is "Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support. I will pass these comments along to the developers in charge of this functionality".

Answer (score 6):

Let's start by observing that the `Exp[-x]` factor can be ignored since `DiracDelta[x]` is zero except at the origin, and at the origin `Exp[-x] == Exp[0] == 1`.  So the expression in question reduces to `DiracDelta[x]`.

Consider the indefinite integral of `DiracDelta[x]`:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x], x]
(* HeavisideTheta[x] *)
```

`HeavisideTheta[x]` is zero to the left of the origin and has the value one to the right as per the definition of Dirac delta.  But at the origin it is indeterminate, just as the Dirac delta itself is indeterminate at that point.

Since the lower limit of integration shown in the question is zero, we will get an indeterminate result when we compute the definite integral:

```
HeavisideTheta[Infinity] - HeavisideTheta[0]
(* 1 - HeavisideTheta[0] *)
```

To avoid this, we must ensure that neither limit of integration is on the origin -- usually on opposite sides.  It is most conventional to use the entire real number line:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* 1 *)
```

... but any finite limits will demonstrate the defined effect of integrating the Dirac delta:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x], {x, -1, 1}]
(* 1 *)
```

**Laplace Transform**

In the particular case of the Laplace transform, *Mathematica* offers [LaplaceTransform](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaplaceTransform.html) which can evade this difficulty .  In the *Details and Options* section of that documentation, we find:

> *The lower limit of the integral is effectively taken to be 0₋, so that the Laplace transform of the Dirac delta function is equal to 1.*

By taking the lower limit to approach zero from the left, the indeterminancy at the origin is avoided:

```
LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[x], x, 1]
(* 1 *)
```

We can achieve the same effect using `Integrate` if we explicitly specify that the lower limit of integration must approach zero from the left:

```
Limit[Integrate[DiracDelta[x]*Exp[-x], {x, z, Infinity}], z -> 0, Direction -> 1]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: -1. I will be waiting for a serious answer. BTW, can you kindly give a reference to definite integrals of distributions? The solid references from my question say nothing about such "integrals" at all.

Comment: @user64494 
+1 The answer is serious! The heuristic definition of the dirac delta distribution   `Integrate[f[x]DiracDelta[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]==f[0]`  implies that `x=0` lies inside the integration range. In your examples you try to Integrate "half range" which isn't defined, as `Heaviside[0]` indicates.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Thank you for your personal opinion though the one is not grounded. Can you give a reference to such "integrals" and their grounds ? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 I'm quite sure that my opinion is "grounded". Perhaps your further progress in understanding distribution might help you to value my comment...

Comment: @WReach: You wrote "To avoid this, we must ensure that neither limit of integration is on the origin -- usually on opposite sides ". How about Integrate[DiracDelta[x]*Exp[-s * x], {x, 0, Infinity}] which performs 1 - HeavisideTheta[0] , being the Laplace transform of DiracDelta?

Comment: I have added a section about avoiding the issue for the particular case of the Laplace transform.  I am not in a position to provide a definitive reference about the treatment of Dirac delta.  I observe that commentators on the 'Net are divided about whether or not the `a` in `Integrate[DiraceDelta[x-a], {x, 0, Infinity}]` must be strictly non-zero (presumably due to different assumptions about limit direction, often unspoken).  Unless someone else chimes in, you might try asking over at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You wrote "In the Details and Options section of that documentation, we find:

The lower limit of the integral is effectively taken to be 0₋, so that the Laplace transform of the Dirac delta function is equal to 1.",but I read "In these distributions, the integration region is taken to start at :0". and the result of LaplaceTransform is in discordance with the result of Integrate.My question is a Mathematica question concerning the results of the certain Mathematica commands.

Comment: I am up voting this answer and down voting the question. I do not see anything wrong to this answer to the level of this website. OP, you want a serious answer, go read all 4 volumes of *Lars Hörmander, Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators, Grundlehren Der Mathematischen Wissenschaften, 256, Springer Verlag, 1983.*

Comment: @SolutionExists: The question may be closed, but the problem will remain open. Perhaps, Mathematica MAX will solve it in the future.

Comment: @user64494 The question of the interpretation of distributions is something that mathematicians posed in 1930 because they couldn't understand how Physicists were making certain calculations. That was solved by a Field medalist ([Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Schwartz)). The problem is NOT open. It has been solved since 1950!

Comment: @SolutionExists: The implementation of the Dirac distribution in Mathematica is primitive and leaves much to be desired. The DiracDelta command is very buggy. Hope, I am clear.

Comment: @user64494 The text you quote also specifies a lower limit of `0₋`, i.e. approaching zero from the left.  I have added a way to express such a lower limit when using `Integrate`.

Comment: @WReach: Thank you for your interpretation. Do you find the result of Integrate[DiracDelta[x]*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}] correct?

Comment: @user64494 Implicit conventions are always a contentious topic, but I think the result is reasonable if we assume that `Integrate` is making no attempt to convert normal limits into one-sided ones.  The result also reflects the fact that there is complexity at the origin.  Personally, I prefer for that complexity to be surfaced rather than hidden.   _Mathematica_ gives us tools to explore and address that complexity.

Comment: @WReach: I prefer arguments over emotional words. BTW, version 7 produces 1/2 for Integrate[DiracDelta[x]*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}] .

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the OP puzzle might be in the manual page for [HeavisideTheta](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html).

> `HeavisideTheta[x]` represents the Heaviside theta function θ(x), equal to 0 for x < 0 and 1 for x > 0.

There is no set value for θ(0) … and there should not be (unless you commit to certain convention). In the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), the plot specifically mentions "using the half-maximum convention" but that is a convention that MMA is not using. Hence, `1 - HeavisideTheta[0]` should be read as *1 minus some value I don't care or know*. That is a perfectly valid answer from MMA.

---

There are many cases where MMA tells you "I don't care or I don't know". In the answer to

```
Solve[Tan[x] == 1]
(*x -> ConditionalExpression[π/4 + π C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers]*)
```

MMA tells you "π/4 plus π times an integer that I don't care or know. It is up to you to decide what integer fits your needs."

In `Heaviside[0]`, MMA implies that it is up to you to pick the convention that suits your needs.

Comment: The statement "Hence, 1 - HeavisideTheta[0] should be read as 1 minus some value I don't care or know." is not grounded. I have never seen such an interpretation. Can you kindly give a reference to definite integrals  of distributions? TIA.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree with your interpretation of the result of Solve[Tan[x] == 1]. I think Mathematica correctly describes all the solutions, no more and no less. In any case, this is another cup of tea. Can you kindly give a reference to definite integrals of distributions?

Comment: @user64494 Sorry, I disagree with your interpretation of the result of `Integrate[DiracDelta[x]*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]`. I think Mathematica correctly describes the solution, no more and no less.  Joking aside, `HeavisideTheta` and distributions in general are not really functions. They are *linear operators* that act on certain spaces of functions. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Distributions) is a good starting point.